# Android 10 - Audio Settings Permission Denial: setSpeakerphoneOn()

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm running on Android 10 and cannot turn on speaker phone using Kotlin.
Below is my code and it will always show False during incall.

MainActivity.kt

```
val audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
audioManager.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION
audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
if (audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn)
    Toast.makeText(this, "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
else
    Toast.makeText(this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Logcat

```
04-18 10:43:58.064  1313  3118 W AS.AudioService: Audio Settings Permission Denial: setSpeakerphoneOn() from pid=8073, uid=10213
```

Comment: I don't even get permission denied. Straight Up doesn't work... by the way, have you found any ways for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue using InCallService which I am using to develop an app as Default Dialer. All you have to do is get the instance of the CallService class which extends InCallService. Since on Android 10 you cannot directly use setSpeakerphoneOn(), which works great on Android 9. InCallService have a method setAudioRoute() which you can use to route your audio. So far I have tested the below code on Android 10 and 9. Also tested Wouter Vanhauwaert issue of alternating between speaker and earpiece during a call which also works fine. My Code is as below.

***CallService.java***

```
public class CallService extends InCallService {

  private static CallService sInstance;
  ……

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
  }
  public static CallService getInstance(){
    return sInstance;
  }
}
```

***AnotherActivity.java***

```
public void toggleSpeaker() {
 AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 boolean isSpeakerOn = audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
 int earpiece = CallAudioState.ROUTE_WIRED_OR_EARPIECE;
 int speaker = CallAudioState.ROUTE_SPEAKER;

 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P){
 CallService.getInstance().setAudioRoute(isSpeakerOn ? earpiece : speaker);
 } else {
   am.setSpeakerphoneOn(!isSpeakerOn);
 }
}
```

Comment: How to do this without using InCallService? I have a webRTC voice call app on webView. and  am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);  doesn’t  change anything  on android 12.

Comment: Hi @SujithManjavana, were you able to find the solution?? I'm also facing the same issue with android 12 that am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false) is not working

Comment: @ShivamSharma did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue: setSpeakerphoneOn does not change the state of isSpeakerphoneOn.

Comment: yes, for android 12 you need to add additional handling @CaitlynCodr

Comment: @ShivamSharma Nice! Could you elaborate a bit more please? I'm really stuck with this. I also posted my own question, I can let you answer it :)

Comment: @CaitlynCodr yes sure. Please share the link of your question.

Comment: @ShivamSharma thanks! This is it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098404/setspeakerphoneon-from-audiomanager-is-not-changing-speakerphone-value-on-androi

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue using java... Also Android 10
When I change the mode before making the call though, it works fine. Only alternating between speaker and earpiece during a call gives issues

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
if(am.isSpeakerphoneOn())
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
else
    am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found Wouter Vanhauwaert to be correct. To clarify: For Android 9 and below, call setSpeakerphoneOn(true) during TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK. For Android 10 and above, call it before starting the phone call activity. For supporting all Android versions, call it in both places.

New update: I find this solution no longer works in Android System Update 28 (android-11.0.0_r28). The version it worked in must have been System Update 23 (android-11.0.0_r23) or earlier.

Comment: Problem is with audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL); It not working. Mode is not changed to MODE_IN_CALL before call, during ringing. At answer is changed automatically, is not needed to change it explicitly. :-(