# Activate speakerphone on Android 10 and above

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So, I'm working on this app where a phone call is made using the TelecomManager and I want to turn on the speakerphone programmatically when an event is triggered in the app.

The app is primarily not made for making phone calls etc, but there's a function that makes phone calls in certain events.

This works fine on android versions below android 10 using the following code:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
am.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, am.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL), 0);
```

But this code doesn't seem to work on android 10 and above.
One solution is to have the speaker on by default when making the phone call, but I want to be able to toggle the speaker via events in the app.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Edit:
The application is only making a call to a specific number in case of an emergency and is not a phone app. And I'd like to be able to start the speaker without having to make the app into the "Default Phone App".

Comment: Check if this helps you, https://stackoverflow.com/a/66829408/11983124

Comment: @Praveen Thanks! I've already tried that, but I didn't get it to work. But then again, my InCallService-methods didn't seem to get triggered at all.

Comment: @Praveen for me doesn't work also, there is any other solution ?

Comment: @DragosUniqQum as far as I know, there is no solution to this to this day.
I've been in contact with Google and they say that it's working as intended.