# Xamarin.Forms Speakerphone NOT Activating on Android 10, 11, 12

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have App that has been working for years on Android 10, 11, 12 to Turn On/Off SpeakerPhone for Inbound and Outbound calls, but now it works sometimes on Inbound calls but never on Outbound calls. Here is a simple BroadcastReciever and MainActivity.

[BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = true)]

[IntentFilter(new[] { TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged })]

public class PhonecallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver

{

```
public override async void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)

{

    Toast.MakeText(context, "Received intent!", ToastLength.Long).Show();



    var state = intent.GetStringExtra(TelephonyManager.ExtraState);

    

    if (intent.Action == TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged)

    {

        if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateRinging)

        {

            //Task.Run(async () =>

            //{

            //    await Task.Delay(1);

            //    Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>

            //    {

            //        MainActivity.audioManager = (AudioManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);

            //        if (!MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn)

            //        { MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true; }

            //        var mode = Mode.Normal;// | Mode.Ringtone | Mode.InCommunication | Mode.Normal;

            //        MainActivity.audioManager.SetRouting(mode, Route.Speaker, Route.All);

            //    });

            //});

            MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;

        }

        else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateOffhook)

        {

            MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true;

        }

        else if (state == TelephonyManager.ExtraStateIdle)

        {

            MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = false; 

        }

    }

}
```

}

In the MainActivity

public static AudioManager audioManager { get; set; }

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        var permissions = new string[]
        {
            Manifest.Permission.ReadPhoneState,
            Manifest.Permission.ModifyAudioSettings, 
            Manifest.Permission.ModifyPhoneState
        };
        ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, permissions, 123);
       
        audioManager = (AudioManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AudioService);
    }
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
      
        if (requestCode == 123 && grantResults.Length > 0 && grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
        {
            RegisterReceiver(new PhonecallReceiver(), new IntentFilter(TelephonyManager.ActionPhoneStateChanged));
        }
    }
```

The above code used to Turn On/Off SpeakerPhone for Inbound/Outbound calls. Now it does not Turn ON the Speakerphone for Outbound Call and sometimes work for Inbound call. My problem is occurring on LG-K51 Android 12 mobile phone that I have Factory Reset.

Thanks

Comment: If you want someone to test your code, make a public github repo containing minimal code needed to replicate the problem. Then maybe someone will test it.

Comment: Did you try to test it on the other android version device or other kinds of device?

Comment: It has been working for two years on 7 different devices. Now two of those LG-K51 Android 10 updated to Android 12 are not able to activate SpeakerphoneOn. Can you please try above code to see if it works for you?

Comment: I have test your code on the android 12 xiaomi device. Once I granted the app the permission about reading the phone state. The broadcast receiver's onreceive method will be called when I called a number or be called in.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure what your last sentence is saying. The OnReceive does execute and OffHook events is triggered on an OutBound call but the SeakerPhone is not activated. MainActivity.audioManager.SpeakerphoneOn = true; executes but fails to activate the SpeakerPhone.

Comment: The third party application didn't have the permission to set the SpeakerphoneOn when the AudioManager.Mode is in call.

Comment: Do you know how to toggle ON/OFF while you execute the above code.

Comment: That seems impossible in the Android 9 and higher version.

Comment: OffHook, Idle, and Ringing are the available events. For an OutBound Call OffHook event does not activate the SpeakerPhone. How may I accomplish activating the SpeakerPhone during an OutBound Call?

Comment: Which one did I miss!??

Comment: Just the system app has the permission to do that.

Comment: This code works flawless on Android 11 and lower for InBound/OutBound calls as is. Now I am wondering if I have led you down a wrong path. I posted so many questions on Microsoft Xamarin Forum and they all have fallen on deaf ear and I wonder if I am saying things that are confusing people.

Comment: Did you update your proeject's target android version?

Comment: The project is set to Android 12 but the target is set for Android 10. I've also tried
Set 13, 12, 11, 10 with target 10, 11, 12 without success. And one of my thread somebody tried this sample on Android studio and said it was not working on that either. Have you tried it with Android Studio.

Comment: If I deploy to Android 11 or lower then the code works most of the time. If I deploy to Android 12 then outbound calls Speakerphone does not activate but inbound call Speakerphone does activate. Android 13 however no SpeakerPhone for InBound/OutBound

Comment: This should be the native android problem. The third party app has no permission to change the audio settings when the phone is in call.

Comment: how to get this permission for outbound call? Is there a way to make speakerphone default without adding bluetooth devices or other devices?

Comment: You have no permissions to do that. You can't change the default phone app's settings.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72098404/setspeakerphoneon-from-audiomanager-is-not-changing-speakerphone-value-on-androi

Comment: I don't understand this. The same permission that allowed it to work for Android 11 and lower is not working under Android 12 and higher. So what is the solution for resolving this???!