# How to Turn ON SpeakerPhone for an Outgoing Call on Android 13

Tags: xamarin.forms

Apparently there are many posts showing how to turn on SpeakerPhone on earlier Android Versions. Those don't work in new OS. Could someone please post a Xamarin.Forms solution!

AudioManager was used in earlier version but current OS is either in need of additional permissions or different API????

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Comment: please post the code that used to work

Comment: Please see this thread.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75270587/xamarin-forms-speakerphone-not-activating-on-android-10-11-12?noredirect=1#comment133280536_75270587                                                                                                        
                       If I deploy to Android 11 or lower then the code works most of the time. If I deploy to Android 12 then outbound calls Speakerphone does not activate but inbound call Speakerphone does activate. Android 13 however no SpeakerPhone for InBound/OutBound